# Create Variable from SELECT QUERY Results

Tags: sql, arrays, azure, variables, select

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
[State_IDs]

FROM [Database].[dbo].[enrollment]
WHERE [Market_State] = 'CO'
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can declare a variable from a SELECT Query... with multiple returns/rows.

I want to use it like an array(?)... I want to pull that list of State IDs, declare it as a variable so I can use it later in my code when I'm pulling data from a different table where I don't have these filter options.

The code below throws me the 'subquery returned more than 1 value' error:

```
DECLARE @CO_IDS VARCHAR(25)
SET @CO_IDS =
    (   
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        [State_IDs]

        FROM [Database].[dbo].[enrollment]
        WHERE [Market_State] = 'CO'
    )
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Add this database to your tags in your question. It is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a table type variable

```
DECLARE @CO_IDS table(CO_ID VARCHAR(25)); 

Insert Into @CO_IDS (CO_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT [State_IDs]
FROM [Database].[dbo].[enrollment]
WHERE [Market_State] = 'CO'

Select CO_ID from @CO_IDS
```